# RealmSwift: Convert Results to Swift Array

Tags: ios, swift, realm

What I want to implement:

```
class func getSomeObject() -> [SomeObject]? {
    let objects = Realm().objects(SomeObject)

    return objects.count > 0 ? objects : nil
}
```

How can I return object as `[SomeObject]` instead if `Results`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a solution. Created extension on Results.

```
extension Results {
    func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var array = [T]()
        for i in 0 ..< count {
            if let result = self[i] as? T {
                array.append(result)
            }
        }

        return array
    }
}
```

and using like

```
class func getSomeObject() -> [SomeObject]? {
    let objects = Realm().objects(SomeObject).toArray(SomeObject) as [SomeObject]

    return objects.count > 0 ? objects : nil
}
```

Comment: `for var i = 0; i < count; i++ ` should be replaced with `for i in 0 ..< count `

Comment: The above is very confusing way of writing the extension: extension Results  { var array: [Element] { return self.map { $0 } } }

Answer (score 447):

Weird, the answer is very straightforward. Here is how I do it:

```
let array = Array(results) // la fin
```

Comment: doesn't it returns an NSArray?

Comment: @thesummersign Realm has been changing a lot recently, but one thing is for sure: The code above returns a Swift `Array` constructed with the results iterator.

Comment: It return nil vars of the entity (initial)

Comment: I agree with @NikKov, it seems to be returning nil vars of the entity ;(

Comment: @Jon How are you seeing that they are nil? It seems like since they are lazy, when you look at them stopped at a debug point they appear empty but if you print them out it accesses them and shows the correct value (for me).

Answer (score 34):

If you absolutely must convert your `Results` to `Array`, keep in mind there's a performance and memory overhead, since `Results` is lazy. But you can do it in one line, as `results.map { $0 }` in swift 2.0 (or `map(results) { $0 }` in 1.2).

Comment: Which version of Realm?

Comment: Isn't this conversion a necessity if you don't want to leak dependency on Realm to too many classes in your project?

Comment: `map { $0 }` will return `LazyMapRandomAccessCollection` in Swift 3, so @Mazyod answer is better.

Comment: @MarcinKuptel yes that's exactly the problem I found. I've been able to abstract away the realm model by creating a struct which conforms to a protocol, and it's this protocol abstraction that I define in my signatures in my codebase. However sometimes I need to convert to an array, is there way I can have a lazy collection of my abstracted protocol so that it only converts to the struct at access time?

Answer (score 22):

With Swift 4.2 it's as simple as an extension:

```
extension Results {
    func toArray() -> [Element] {
      return compactMap {
        $0
      }
    }
 }
```

All the needed generics information is already a part of `Results` which we extend.

To use this:

```
let someModelResults: Results<SomeModel> = realm.objects(SomeModel.self)
let someModelArray: [SomeModel] = someModelResults.toArray()
```

Comment: How do you use that function?

Comment: realm.objects(SomeModel.self).toArray()

Answer (score 9):

This an another way of converting `Results` into Array with an extension with **Swift 3** in a single line.

```
extension Results {
    func toArray() -> [T] {
        return self.map { $0 }
    }
}
```

For **Swift 4** and Xcode 9.2

```
extension Results {
    func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return flatMap { $0 as? T }
    }
}
```

With **Xcode 10** `flatMap` is deprecated you can use `compactMap` for mapping.

```
extension Results {
    func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return compactMap { $0 as? T }
    }
}
```

Comment: As i am using this code in 9.2 version of XCode, it shows me Use of undeclared type 'T'

Comment: Updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: For Xcode 10 and above you can use compactMap instead of flatMap to avoid the warning.

Comment: Hi! Can you please say how to call toArray func? I need to convert Results<Int> to [Int].

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3**

```
extension Results {
    func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var array = [T]()
        for i in 0 ..< count {
            if let result = self[i] as? T {
                array.append(result)
            }
        }

        return array
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class func getSomeObject() -> [SomeObject]? {
   let defaultRealm = try! Realm()
    let objects = defaultRealm.objects(SomeObject.self).toArray(ofType : SomeObject.self) as [SomeObject]

    return objects.count > 0 ? objects : nil
}
```

**Alternative : Using generics**

```
class func getSomeObject() -> [T]? {
        let objects = Realm().objects(T.self as! Object.Type).toArray(ofType : T.self) as [T]

        return objects.count > 0 ? objects : nil
}
```

Answer (score 4):

it's not a good idea to convert Results to Array, because Results is lazy. But if you need try this:

```
func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return flatMap { $0 as? T }
}
```

but better way is to pass Results wherever you need. Also you can convert Results to List instead of Array.

```
List(realm.objects(class))
```

if the first func is not working you can try this one:

```
var refrenceBook:[RefrenceProtocol] = []
let faceTypes = Array(realm.objects(FaceType))
refrenceBook = faceTypes.map({$0 as FaceType})
```

Comment: After updating RealmSwift to 3.4.0, List does not take arguments.
How to convert an array to List in this case? Any idea?

Comment: @NishuPriya here you are         let myList = List<Person>()
        myList.append(objectsIn: realm.objects(Person.self))

Answer (score 3):

Solution for **Swift 4, Realm 3**

```
extension Results {
    func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
        let array = Array(self) as! [T]
        return array
    }
}
```

Now converting can be done as below

```
let array = Realm().objects(SomeClass).toArray(ofType: SomeClass.self)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, if there is any efficient way to do this.

But you can do it by create a Swift array and append it in the loop.

```
class func getSomeObject() -> [SomeObject]? {
    var someObjects: [SomeObject] = []
    let objects = Realm().objects(SomeObject)
    for object in objects{
        someObjects += [object]
    }
    return objects.count > 0 ? someObjects : nil
}
```

If you feel it's too slow. I recommend you to pass around Realm `Results` object directly.

Comment: I did something like that only by creating an extension on Resules instead. I have posted the code as answer. Thanks :)

Comment: yeah. I would do that too.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension Results {
    var array: [Element]? {
        return self.count > 0 ? self.map { $0 } : nil
    }
}
```

So, you can use like:

```
Realm().objects(SomeClass.self).filter("someKey ENDSWITH %@", "sth").array
```

Answer (score 2):

```swift
extension Results {
    func materialize() -> [Element] {
        return Array(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Swift 5 and RealmSwift v10.20.0**

This methods works:

```
private func convertToArray<R>(results: Results<R>) -> [R] where R: Object {
    var arrayOfResults: [R] = []
    for result in results {
        arrayOfResults.append(result)
    }
    return arrayOfResults
}
```