# Realm is returning an empty object when I convert it to an array

Tags: xcode, swift, realm

Using Realm in a Swift application. I'm fetching users from Realm and want to return an array of users (as my app also uses Parse, it's easier if they are all arrays I'm guessing).

Here is my code:

```
class func fetchUsersFromDB() -> [User]{
    var users = [User]()
    let realm = Realm()
    var allUsers = realm.objects(User)
    users = Array(allUsers)
    return users
}
```

When I do a dump of `allUsers` I can see a Realm result. But when I dump `users` it shows me the object with default values.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here is how I declare the User model

```
class User: Object {
    dynamic var objectId: String = ""
    dynamic var username: String = ""
    dynamic var password: String = ""
    dynamic var emailVerified: Bool = false
    dynamic var email: String = ""
    dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    dynamic var defaultRelationshipId: String = ""
    dynamic var picture: NSData = NSData()
    dynamic var updatedAt: NSDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var createdAd: NSDate = NSDate()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "objectId"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you look at this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100011/realmswift-convert-results-to-swift-array

Comment: @Shripada That doesn't work.