# How do I sort Realm Results by a keypath of the first item in a to-many relationship?

Tags: swift, sorting, realm, keypaths

My model has an `GroupOfEvents` realm object that has a to-many relationship to `Event` realm object via the property `events`. Each `Event` has a `date` property.

I have a `Results<GroupOfEvents>` and I want to sort by the `date` of the first event in `events`. If I were sorting a regular swift array, it would look like:

```
groupsOfEvents.sorted(by: { $0.events.first!.date > $1.events.first!.date })
```

Here is my failed attempt to sort a `Results<GroupOfEvents>`:

```
groupsOfEvents.sorted(byKeyPath: "events.first.date")
```

It gives the error:

> 'Cannot sort on key path 'events.first.date': property 'GroupOfEvents.events' is of unsupported type 'array'.'

How can I sort it the way I want?

---

Questions  you might ask me:

Why are you sorting by the first event's date? That's not something people usually do.

In fact, `GroupOfEvents` contains events with the same date, so using the date of any event in `events` will work.

Why don't you just move the `date` property to `GroupOfEvents`?

Yes, I could do that, but I am looking for alternatives to that.

Why don't you get rid of `GroupOfEvents` and just get all the `Events` then group by the date?

Although all `events` in a `GroupOfEvents` have the same date. The events of two different `GroupOfEvents` can have the same date as well. There are other properties that differentiates `GroupOfEvents`.

Comment: You can't filter nor sort based on array of primitives. Yeah I know, I wish you could, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Realm's header files I see this comment:

> Collections may only be sorted by properties of `boolean`, `Date`, `NSDate`, single and double-precision `floating point`, `integer`, and `string` types.

That means that your array of events is not a supported key-path, just as the error you are receiving is saying.

### Update

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32456833/831838) answer you can cast an object of type `Results` to an array. So you could try something along these lines:

```
let groupsOfEventsSortedArray = Array(groupsOfEvents).sorted { $0.events.first!.date > $1.events.first!.date }
```

Comment: Are you saying that what I am trying to do is impossible?

Comment: Using the provided method I think so, yes. Please see my updated answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can't do that. It should be describe in any "realm limitation list", but it doesn't. In fact, there is an issue on github for this problem: [Support of keypath sorting for to-many relationships](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4554).

And here is some workaround about the problem:

1. The best solution will be to add `firstEvent: Event` to `GroupOfEvents` model. The [Support sorting by keypath](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1277) says, that you can sort by `.sorted(byKeyPath: "firstEvent.date")`. But it introduces extra work to sync the `firstEvent` and `events.first`.
2. The cheapest way for programmer and potentially the worst for efficiency - cast to `Array` and then sort. Very simple, but as you know realm gives you object only when you start working with it (i.e. they place `lazy` everywhere they can). If you haven't a big amount of data - this should works well.

---

Also, Realm has nice [NSPredicate Cheatsheet](https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/), that covers useful patterns and mark supported cases by pink dot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but the `Results` class has a`sorted` function that accepts a `Sequence` (see the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:10RealmSwift7ResultsC6sortedACyxGqd__2by_ts8SequenceRd__AA14SortDescriptorV7ElementRtd__lF)). Hence, you can just do the following:

```
func sortGroupOfEvents(e1: GroupOfEvents, e2: GroupOfEvents) -> Bool{
    guard let date1 = e1.events.first?.date else {return false}
    guard let date2 = e2.events.first?.date else {return true}
    return date1 > date2
}

groupsOfEvents.sorted(by: sortGroupOfEvents)
```